# Go time.Format wrong month

Tags: time, go, format

I'd like to rename some files based on their modification date.

When I use the `time.Format` method to get the correct string, basically in this format `YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS`, the day has a trailing `0`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")

    const layout = "2006-01-20_15-04-05"

    t := time.Date(2013, 07, 23, 21, 32, 39, 0, loc)
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(t.Format(layout))
}
```

[Click to play](http://play.golang.org/p/OTxEqscA-0)

Output:

```
2013-07-23 21:32:39 +0200 CEST
2013-07-230_21-32-39
```

Comment: The month or the day? I can see the trailing `0` in the day. Or do you want your month to be `7`, not `07`?

Comment: By the way, be careful about using leading zeros as part of your numeric literals in your Go programs.  I saw the literal `07` in your program and instinctively winced.  If you aren't careful, you might use **octal** by accident.  https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals.  In the case above, it's not technically a problem, but in general, use octal integer literals only when you really mean octal.

Comment: @Ainar-G Oh sorry, of course i mean a trailing 0 in the day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `layout` isn't using the reference date: change it to  `"2006-01-02_15-04-05"`

When you use `"2006-01-20_15-04-05"`, the formatter see the `2`, and uses that for the day, then keeps the extra `0` since it doesn't match any part of the reference date.